# VS 2019 changes not visible before re-debugging project

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

So i have just upgraded to Visual Studio 2019 and created new ASP.NET Core project. There i have added some views/css and i hit `Debug`.

Problem comes when i change some code in `.cshtml` or `.css` while `debugging` is on. I refresh my page in browser and it doesn't load new content inside that file. It was totally normal thing in 2017.

What to do?

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET Core 3?

Comment: No, i am using 2.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a [known issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/467490/updating-cshtml-does-not-update-on-page-reload.html) in Visual Studio 2019 ,try the following steps:

1. Install the latest version of **Visual Studio 2019 16.3.7** .
2. For change some code in `.cshtml`

   (1)  Asp.net core 2.2 , you could load the new content after refreshing the page in browser.

   (2)  Asp.net core 3.0

   - Add NuGet package **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation**
   - Update startup.cs `services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();`
3. For getting the last version of js and css files , you should add `asp-append-version="true"` to your file references like:

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true"/>
   ```

   Reference:https://forums.asp.net/t/2154606.aspx?CSS+style+change+not+updated+on+the+website+until+browser+history+is+cleaned